# I need to validate credit-card details

Tags: php, validation, magento

I need to validate the credit-card details such as

```
Card Type
Card Number 
Card CVV number 
Card Exper Date
```

My need is to verify all the above details are valid currently.

Could you help me, how to overcome this?

Comment: Does you credit card processor not do this for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Magento comes with [Really Easy Field Validation](http://tetlaw.id.au/view/javascript/really-easy-field-validation) in place so you only need to add some classes to the fields in question.

- `validate-cc-type` or `validate-cc-type-select`
- `validate-cc-number`
- `validate-cc-cvn`
- `validate-cc-exp`

However the normal payment modules should already be using these so what are you doing that breaks it or otherwise needs CC details?

Comment: I also need to validate the give card is currently valid or expired.

Comment: cc-number is a simple modulus 10 lun code calculation easily done in javascript. 
cc-type is a simple prefix calculation done in javascript. Validation of both is a function already included in the USAePay and Authorize.NET modules.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your question:

- [What is the best way to validate a credit card in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/174730/what-is-the-best-way-to-validate-a-credit-card-in-php)

The answer is comprehensive and addresses your question properly.

An alternate is to fully hand-off the details and the processing to a 3rd party, which removes the risk on your and the obligation to be PCI-DSS compliant

CVV validation can only be performed through interaction with a provider.  Simple rules do exist, for example:

- AMEX -- 4 digit CVV
- Everyone else -- 3 digit CVV

Of course, let me state, that this may not be entirely accurate and you should refer to other, slightly more accurate resources:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Card_security_code

Comment: While you can check string length, the number is arbitrary and non-calculable which is the point of the exercise. It must match against the card processor's database info.

Comment: I need to validate the given card is active now. It is to restrict users to give inactive/expired cards.