# What is the best way to validate a credit card in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, credit-card

hi i am using codeigniter . i want to validate my credit card details . i saw there are classes in php to validate credit card numbers . i saw a helper in codeigniter to validate credit cards

http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Credit_Card_Helper

```
/**
 * Truncates a card number retaining only the first 4 and the last 4 digits.  It then returns the truncated form.
 *
 * @param string The card number to truncate.
 * @return string The truncated card number.
 */
function truncate_card($card_num) {
    $padsize = (strlen($card_num) < 7 ? 0 : strlen($card_num) - 7);
    return substr($card_num, 0, 4) . str_repeat('X', $padsize). substr($card_num, -3);
}


/**
 * Validates a card expiry date.  Finds the midnight on first day of the following 
 * month and ensures that is greater than the current time (cards expire at the 
 * end of the printed month).  Assumes basic sanity checks have already been performed 
 * on month/year (i.e. length, numeric, etc).
 *
 * @param integer The expiry month shown on the card.
 * @param integer The expiry year printed on the card.
 * @return boolean Returns true if the card is still valid, false if it has expired.
 */
function card_expiry_valid($month, $year) {
    $expiry_date = mktime(0, 0, 0, ($month + 1), 1, $year);
    return ($expiry_date > time());
}


/**
 * Strips all non-numerics from the card number.
 *
 * @param string The card number to clean up.
 * @return string The stripped down card number.
 */
function card_number_clean($number) {
    return ereg_replace("[^0-9]", "", $number); 
}


/**
 * Uses the Luhn algorithm (aka Mod10) <http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm> 
 * to perform basic validation of a credit card number.
 *
 * @param string The card number to validate.
 * @return boolean True if valid according to the Luhn algorith, false otherwise.
 */
function card_number_valid ($card_number) {
    $card_number = strrev(card_number_clean($card_number));
    $sum = 0;

    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($card_number); $i++) {
      $digit = substr($card_number, $i, 1);

        // Double every second digit
        if ($i % 2 == 1) {
          $digit *= 2;
        }

        // Add digits of 2-digit numbers together
        if ($digit > 9)    {
          $digit = ($digit % 10) + floor($digit / 10);
        }

        $sum += $digit;
    }

    // If the total has no remainder it's OK
    return ($sum % 10 == 0);
}
?>
```

it uses a common validation . but i want a validation according to card type like this

http://www.braemoor.co.uk/software/creditcard.php

is there any libraries or helpers in codeigniter . please help.....................

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to validate a credit card in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/174730/what-is-the-best-way-to-validate-a-credit-card-in-php) applicable for PHP

Comment: Have you thought about porting that code you linked to to a CI plugin?

Comment: @Jared Farrish  , nop not yet , i want to know is there any existing ones in codeigniter . if not i will port it to codeigniter

Comment: @ajreal , i want a codeigniter solution . PHP solution will not help

Comment: @Kanishka Panamaldeniya - How does a CodeIgniter solution differ from a PHP solution? CodeIgniter helpers are just regular PHP functions!!

Comment: @KanishkaPanamaldeniya huh? Do you know CI is written in PHP?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As people already told you, CodeIgniter is a php framework, coded using php, works in a php environment and makes use of..,php classes and functions :).

What's more, the file you linked to is a simple function. One function. You know what you can do? Take the file as it is, name it `creditcard_helper.php`, put it inside the helpers folder, open it and place the whole code inside this snippet (ugly but necessary, as whenever you'll load the helper a second time it would give you error otherwise):

```
if(!function_exists('checkCreditCard')
{
   //the whole content goes here untouched;
}
```

And you're set. Just use:

```
$this->load->helper('creditcard');
if(checkCreditCard($cardnumber, $cardname, &$errornumber, &$errortext))
{
  echo 'card OK';
}
else
{
 echo 'wrong card type/number';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found [this helper](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/wiki/Credit-Card-Helper) inside the [CodeIgniter Github wiki page](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/wiki/). When dropped inside your `helpers` folder, you can then use the functions from the file in a controller or model you load it in.