# Formatting input value using javascript as the user types a value into the input field

Tags: javascript, html, regex, formatting

I have an input field of length 14 into which the user types a value. As the user types into it, I would like a space to be added automatically after first 2 characters and then after next 3 characters and then after next 3 characters. so if the user wants to enter **12345678901**, it should be formatted to **12 345 678 901**.

Also when user uses backspace to clear the characters, the space should automatically be removed. So in the above case when the cursor reaches 9 and user hits backspace, the cursor should move two places to left clearing 9 and the space before it.

I tried following the credit card formatting here [Format credit card number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36833366/format-credit-card-number) but couldn't understnd how it is done. The code from above link is

```
formatInput(event: any) {
    var v = event.value.replace(/\s+/g, '').replace(/[^0-9]/gi, '')
    var matches = v.match(/\d{4,16}/g);
    var match = matches && matches[0] || ''
    var parts = []

    for (let i=0, len=match.length; i<len; i+=4) {
       parts.push(match.substring(i, i+4))
    }

    if (parts.length) {
      (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("txtInput")).value = 
        parts.join(' ')
    } else {
        (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("txtInput")).value 
          = event.value;
    }
}
```

The above code generates spaces after every 4 digits. My requirement is to accept any characters and generate spaces after first 2 characters and then after next 3 characters and then after next 3 characters. Please help me out with this.

Comment: You should share your current code in order to see where you are going wrong.

Comment: There are too many nuances with these solutions, and they all depend on your current code. So, please start on it, do something, and then please come back with a more specific question.

Comment: I added the code now in the question

Comment: Maybe `var matches = v.split(/(?<=^\d{2})|\B(?=(?<=\d{4})(?:\d{3})+$)/)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a working example that solves your problem.

```js
function format(str) {
 if (str.length < 2) return str
  else {
    let [fl,sl,...lstr] = str
    lstr =lstr.reduce((acc, el, i) => (i % 3 ? acc[acc.length - 1]+=el : acc.push(el), acc),[])
  return `${fl}${sl} ${lstr.join(' ')}`.trim()
  }
}



const [input,result]= document.querySelectorAll('#input,#result')
input.oninput =()=>{
    const i = input.value.replace(/\s/g, '');
    input.value= format(i)
  }
```

```html
<input type=text id=input />
<p id="result"></p>
```

Comment: Abdel: Your solution fixed the problem. Thank you so much :)

Comment: There is one issue I noticed. If the value is 12 345 678 901 and if I focus the cursor to just after any space i.e before 3 or 6 or 9 and click backspace, the cursor moves to the end of the value i.e after last 1. For example if I focus the cursor to just before 3 and click backspace, the cursor moves to end of the value without actually deleting the space. How to fix this issue?

Comment: this behavior is expected because deleting a space retrigger the function that reformats the input so space takes its place again

Comment: Okay. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Abdel. Can you also please elaborate on what each line does in the above function?