# how to validate all the testing stripe dummy card numbers

Tags: laravel

I am using stripe payment integration and want to validate all the testing card numbers dynamically.
this is my code for validating only one number.

```
     if ($expe[0] === 4242424242424242  )
     {

     }
     else
     {
       return back()->withErrors('Add a valid card no ');
     }
```

Comment: is the valid number exists in a database table?

Comment: Place them all in an array, then compare for the existence of `$expe[0]` `in_array()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to validate a credit card in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/174730/what-is-the-best-way-to-validate-a-credit-card-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

I use an [abstract class](https://gist.github.com/whoacowboy/63c29de1075283d878ca78c2061e63f5) with a bunch of the stripe credit cards. Then I create the needed arrays with the `const` in my test classes.

```
<?php namespace App;

abstract class StripeToken
{
    const BYPASS_PENDING_TOKEN = 'tok_bypassPending';
    const BYPASS_PENDING_CC = '4000000000000077';
    const BYPASS_PENDING_LAST4 = '0077';
    const BYPASS_PENDING_DESC = 'Charge succeeds and funds will be added directly to your available balance (bypassing your pending balance).';

    const DOMESTIC_PRICING_TOKEN = 'tok_domesticPricing';
    const DOMESTIC_PRICING_CC = '4000000000000093';
    const DOMESTIC_PRICING_LAST4 = '0093';
    const DOMESTIC_PRICING_DESC = 'Charge succeeds and domestic pricing is used (other test cards use international pricing). This card is only significant in countries with split pricing.';

    const AVS_FAIL_TOKEN = 'tok_avsFail';
    const AVS_FAIL_CC = '4000000000000010';
    const AVS_FAIL_LAST4 = '0010';
    const AVS_FAIL_DESC = 'The address_line1_check and address_zip_check verifications fail. If your account is blocking payments that fail ZIP code validation, the charge is declined.';

    const AVS_LINE1_FAIL_TOKEN = 'tok_avsLine1Fail';
    const AVS_LINE1_FAIL_CC = '4000000000000028';
    const AVS_LINE1_FAIL_LAST4 = '0028';
    const AVS_LINE1_FAIL_DESC = 'Charge succeeds but the address_line1_check verification fails.';

    const AVS_ZIP_FAIL_TOKEN = 'tok_avsZipFail';
    const AVS_ZIP_FAIL_CC = '4000000000000036';
    const AVS_ZIP_FAIL_LAST4 = '0036';
    const AVS_ZIP_FAIL_DESC = 'The address_zip_check verification fails. If your account is blocking payments that fail ZIP code validation, the charge is declined.';

    const AVS_UNCHECKED_TOKEN = 'tok_avsUnchecked';
    const AVS_UNCHECKED_CC = '4000000000000044';
    const AVS_UNCHECKED_LAST4 = '0044';
    const AVS_UNCHECKED_DESC = 'Charge succeeds but the address_zip_check and address_line1_check verifications are both unavailable.';

    const CVC_CHECK_FAIL_TOKEN = 'tok_cvcCheckFail';
    const CVC_CHECK_FAIL_CC = '4000000000000101';
    const CVC_CHECK_FAIL_LAST4 = '0101';
    const CVC_CHECK_FAIL_DESC = 'If a CVC number is provided, the cvc_check fails. If your account is blocking payments that fail CVC code validation, the charge is declined.';

    const CHARGE_CUSTOMER_FAIL_TOKEN = 'tok_chargeCustomerFail';
    const CHARGE_CUSTOMER_FAIL_CC = '4000000000000341';
    const CHARGE_CUSTOMER_FAIL_LAST4 = '0341';
    const CHARGE_CUSTOMER_FAIL_DESC = 'Attaching this card to a Customer object succeeds, but attempts to charge the customer fail.';
    const CHARGE_CUSTOMER_FAIL_MESSAGE = 'Your card was declined.';

    const RISK_LEVEL_ELEVATED_TOKEN = 'tok_riskLevelElevated';
    const RISK_LEVEL_ELEVATED_CC = '4000000000009235';
    const RISK_LEVEL_ELEVATED_LAST4 = '9235';
    const RISK_LEVEL_ELEVATED_DESC = 'Charge succeeds with a risk_level of elevated and placed into review.';

    const CHARGE_DECLINED_TOKEN = 'tok_chargeDeclined';
    const CHARGE_DECLINED_CC = '4000000000000002';
    const CHARGE_DECLINED_LAST4 = '0002';
    const CHARGE_DECLINED_DESC = 'Charge is declined with a card_declined code.';
    const CHARGE_DECLINED_MESSAGE = 'Your card was declined.';

    const CHARGE_DECLINED_FRAUDULENT_TOKEN = 'tok_chargeDeclinedFraudulent';
    const CHARGE_DECLINED_FRAUDULENT_CC = '4100000000000019';
    const CHARGE_DECLINED_FRAUDULENT_LAST4 = '0019';
    const CHARGE_DECLINED_FRAUDULENT_DESC = 'Charge is declined with a card_declined code and a fraudulent reason.';
    const CHARGE_DECLINED_FRAUDULENT_MESSAGE = 'Your card was declined.';

    const CHARGE_DECLINED_INCORRECT_CVC_TOKEN = 'tok_chargeDeclinedIncorrectCvc';
    const CHARGE_DECLINED_INCORRECT_CVC_CC = '4000000000000127';
    const CHARGE_DECLINED_INCORRECT_CVC_LAST4 = '0127';
    const CHARGE_DECLINED_INCORRECT_CVC_DESC = 'Charge is declined with an incorrect_cvc code.';
    const CHARGE_DECLINED_INCORRECT_CVC_MESSAGE = 'Your card\'s security code is incorrect.';

    const CHARGE_DECLINED_EXPIRED_CARD_TOKEN = 'tok_chargeDeclinedExpiredCard';
    const CHARGE_DECLINED_EXPIRED_CARD_CC = '4000000000000069';
    const CHARGE_DECLINED_EXPIRED_CARD_LAST4 = '0069';
    const CHARGE_DECLINED_EXPIRED_CARD_DESC = 'Charge is declined with an expired_card code.';
    const CHARGE_DECLINED_EXPIRED_CARD_MESSAGE = 'Your card has expired.';

    const CHARGE_DECLINED_PROCESSING_ERROR_TOKEN = 'tok_chargeDeclinedProcessingError';
    const CHARGE_DECLINED_PROCESSING_ERROR_CC = '4000000000000119';
    const CHARGE_DECLINED_PROCESSING_ERROR_LAST4 = '0119';
    const CHARGE_DECLINED_PROCESSING_ERROR_DESC = 'Charge is declined with a processing_error code.';
    const CHARGE_DECLINED_PROCESSING_ERROR_MESSAGE = 'An error occurred while processing your card. Try again in a little bit.';

    const CHARGE_DECLINED_INCORRECT_NUMBER_CC = '4242424242424241';
    const CHARGE_DECLINED_INCORRECT_NUMBER_LAST4 = '4241';
    const CHARGE_DECLINED_INCORRECT_NUMBER_DESC = 'Charge is declined with an incorrect_number code as the card number fails the Luhn check.';

    const VISA_TOKEN = 'tok_visa';
    const VISA_CC = '4242424242424242';
    const VISA_LAST4 = '4242';
    const VISA_DESC = 'Visa';
    const VISA_BRAND = 'Visa';

    const VISA_DEBIT_TOKEN = 'tok_visa_debit';
    const VISA_DEBIT_CC = '4000056655665556';
    const VISA_DEBIT_LAST4 = '5556';
    const VISA_DEBIT_DESC = 'Visa (debit)';
    const VISA_DEBIT_BRAND = 'Visa';

    const MASTERCARD_TOKEN = 'tok_mastercard';
    const MASTERCARD_CC = '5555555555554444';
    const MASTERCARD_LAST4 = '4444';
    const MASTERCARD_DESC = 'Mastercard';
    const MASTERCARD_BRAND = 'Mastercard';

    const MASTERCARD_DEBIT_TOKEN = 'tok_mastercard_debit';
    const MASTERCARD_DEBIT_CC = '5200828282828210';
    const MASTERCARD_DEBIT_LAST4 = '8210';
    const MASTERCARD_DEBIT_DESC = 'Mastercard (debit)';
    const MASTERCARD_DEBIT_BRAND = 'Mastercard';

    const MASTERCARD_PREPAID_TOKEN = 'tok_mastercard_prepaid';
    const MASTERCARD_PREPAID_CC = '5105105105105100';
    const MASTERCARD_PREPAID_LAST4 = '5100';
    const MASTERCARD_PREPAID_DESC = 'Mastercard (prepaid)';
    const MASTERCARD_PREPAID_BRAND = 'Mastercard';

    const AMEX_TOKEN = 'tok_amex';
    const AMEX_CC = '378282246310005';
    const AMEX_LAST4 = '0005';
    const AMEX_DESC = 'American Express';
    const AMEX_BRAND = 'American Express';

    const DISCOVER_TOKEN = 'tok_discover';
    const DISCOVER_CC = '6011000990139424';
    const DISCOVER_LAST4 = '9424';
    const DISCOVER_DESC = 'Discover';
    const DISCOVER_BRAND = 'Discover';

    const DISCOVER_2_CC = '6011111111111117';
    const DISCOVER_2_LAST4 = '1117';
    const DISCOVER_2_DESC = 'Discover';
    const DISCOVER_2_BRAND = 'Discover';

    const DINERS_TOKEN = 'tok_diners';
    const DINERS_CC = '30569309025904';
    const DINERS_LAST4 = '5904';
    const DINERS_DESC = 'Diners Club';
    const DINERS_BRAND = 'Diners Club';

    const JCB_TOKEN = 'tok_jcb';
    const JCB_CC = '3530111333300000';
    const JCB_LAST4 = '0000';
    const JCB_DESC = 'JCB';
    const JCB_BRAND = 'JCB';

    const VISA_2_CC = '4012888888881881';
    const VISA_2_LAST4 = '1881';
    const VISA_2_DESC = 'Visa';
    const VISA_2_BRAND = 'Visa';

    const AMEX_2_CC = '371449635398431';
    const AMEX_2_LAST4 = '8431';
    const AMEX_2_DESC = 'American Express';
    const AMEX_2_BRAND = 'American Express';


    const DINERS_2_CC = '38520000023237';
    const DINERS_2_LAST4 = '3237';
    const DINERS_2_DESC = 'Diners Club';
    const DINERS_2_BRAND = 'Diners Club';

    const JCB_2_CC = '3566002020360505';
    const JCB_2_LAST4 = '0505';
    const JCB_2_DESC = 'JCB';
    const JCB_2_BRAND = 'JCB';

    const VALID_CC_NUMBERS = [
        [
            'token' => StripeToken::VISA_TOKEN,
            'number' => StripeToken::VISA_CC,
            'last4' => StripeToken::VISA_LAST4,
            'brand' => StripeToken::VISA_BRAND
        ],
        [
            'token' => StripeToken::VISA_DEBIT_TOKEN,
            'number' => StripeToken::VISA_DEBIT_CC,
            'last4' => StripeToken::VISA_DEBIT_LAST4,
            'brand' => StripeToken::VISA_DEBIT_BRAND
        ],
        [
            'token' => StripeToken::MASTERCARD_TOKEN,
            'number' => StripeToken::MASTERCARD_CC,
            'last4' => StripeToken::MASTERCARD_LAST4,
            'brand' => StripeToken::MASTERCARD_BRAND
        ],
        [
            'token' => StripeToken::MASTERCARD_DEBIT_TOKEN,
            'number' => StripeToken::MASTERCARD_DEBIT_CC,
            'last4' => StripeToken::MASTERCARD_DEBIT_LAST4,
            'brand' => StripeToken::MASTERCARD_DEBIT_BRAND
        ],
        [
            'token' => StripeToken::MASTERCARD_PREPAID_TOKEN,
            'number' => StripeToken::MASTERCARD_PREPAID_CC,
            'last4' => StripeToken::MASTERCARD_PREPAID_LAST4,
            'brand' => StripeToken::MASTERCARD_PREPAID_BRAND
        ],
        [
            'token' => StripeToken::AMEX_TOKEN,
            'number' => StripeToken::AMEX_CC,
            'last4' => StripeToken::AMEX_LAST4,
            'brand' => StripeToken::AMEX_BRAND
        ],
        [
            'token' => StripeToken::DISCOVER_TOKEN,
            'number' => StripeToken::DISCOVER_CC,
            'last4' => StripeToken::DISCOVER_LAST4,
            'brand' => StripeToken::DISCOVER_BRAND
        ],
        [
            'token' => StripeToken::DINERS_TOKEN,
            'number' => StripeToken::DINERS_CC,
            'last4' => StripeToken::DINERS_LAST4,
            'brand' => StripeToken::DINERS_BRAND
        ],
        [
            'token' => StripeToken::JCB_TOKEN,
            'number' => StripeToken::JCB_CC,
            'last4' => StripeToken::JCB_LAST4,
            'brand' => StripeToken::JCB_BRAND
        ],
    ];

    /**
     * Get a random valid cc array
     * @return mixed
     */
    public static function randomValidCC(){
        return static::VALID_CC_NUMBERS[array_rand(static::VALID_CC_NUMBERS, 1)];
    }
}
```